# I'm using git-svn and I accidentally typed 'git svn rebase' on my feature branch, what are the ramifications?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm using git-svn and I accidentally typed `git svn rebase` on my feature branch, what are the ramifications?

Normally I type `git svn rebase` on master, then I'll type `git rebase master feature` to update the feature branch.  Is it safe to checkout master, do a `git svn rebase` and skip the second step?  I'm hoping that will be equivalent to what I normally do.

I'm afraid I'll cause issues once I `merge --ff-only` from feature back into master and `dcommit` master.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your reflog (`git log -g`) to go back to where you were on the feature branch before the accidental `git svn rebase`.  The `git svn fetch` component of the original command is fine so there's no need to `git svn reset` that.  You can just go to your master branch and do the `git svn rebase` as usual to clean things up.

As you say, there may not be any issue at all since you planed to do a rebase of that feature branch anyway.

Comment: There doesn't *seem* to be an issue.  I did exactly what I was planning as per my question. Then I looked at the log.  My history was still linear.  I was lucky in that my branch didn't actually have any changes in it compared to master (I initially thought it did).  I'm not sure if this would have worked out the same if it had changes.  But based on my understanding of what rebase does, I don't see why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I use a git svn repository mapped to a single svn branch. I did the same lately and I had no problems. I even did a dcommit directly from the feature git branch. In any case, you can always show the commits locally before dcommiting to make sure every thing is fine prior to further actions.